# 2D Array Interpolation

Tags: c#, interpolation, multidimensional-array

i am currently working on a 3D game in c#. I have a 2 dimensional array called `data` where i get a `z` value for my `x` and `y` values. 
for example:

```
data[x,y] = z;
data[1,2] = 4;
data[2,4] = 5;
```

etc.
my problem is that this is very vague and I also need the calculated (interpolated) values for example x=1.5 and y=2.5. How can I get to this value and are there any functions available?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by `x=1,5 and y=2,5`

Comment: Ohh i'm sorry, i am European I mean x=1.5 and y=2.5

Comment: You have to decide on an interpolation strategy first.

Comment: @Muctadir In many countries, the `,` is used as the decimal separator.

Comment: So given a point `data[1,2]` and a point `data[2,3]` you want to know what a point half way between them would look like? Is that correct? In that case as @DavidHeffernan said, you need to decide what the function looks like. Is it linear? Curved? Something else?

Comment: @david but which strategy can I use, I am new to interpolation?

Comment: @hashtag7: That's not a question anybody except the domain expert (i.e. you) can answer.

Comment: @hashtag7: Well then, what's the equation that describes that curve? How do you generate your points in the first place?

Comment: I think I should use polynomial interpolation or something like that??

Comment: In my applications, I have triangulated the X/Y data, and then fitted a surface over that triangulation. That surface could be linear, or it could be higher order depending on your application needs. I've done both linear and higher order to meet different demands.

Comment: @Matt there is no function, I get the values from my heightmap image

Comment: @hashtag7 It's trivially easy to say "polynomial interpolation". Writing code to a well-defined algorithm is another matter.

Comment: @david i only did interpolation with 2d plots where it is easy to find a linear value between two points, because it is linear and in 2d. There is one value after another one. If I need f(3.5) and I have f(4) and f(3) it is easy to find linear. But when I work with 3d and I need a value f(1.5, 2.5) but there is only one for f(2,3) and f(1,2) I don't know how I can calculate this linear

Comment: Look into section 3.6 of the numerical recipes book http://www.nrbook.com/c/

Answer (score 13):

Maybe *Bilinear Interpolation* can be used in your scenario:

```
float fractionX = ... //the fraction part of the x coordinate
float integerX = ... //the integer part of the x coordinate
float fractionY, integerY = ...
interpolatedValue = (1 - fractionX) * 
                        ((1 - fractionY) * data[integerX, integerY] + 
                         fractionY * data[integerX, integerY + 1]) + 
                    fractionX * 
                        ((1 - fractionY) * data[integerX + 1, integerY] + 
                        fractionY * data[integerX + 1, integerY + 1]);
```

Interpolating between 0, 4, 1 and 3 yields the following result:

[image: Bilinear interpolation]

If you have triangulated the height map, *Barycentric Interpolation* might be more appropriate:

```
//Assuming the following triangle alignment:
//  1 +--+--+--+
//    | /| /| /|
//    |/ |/ |/ |
//  0 +--+--+--+

if (fractionX < fractionY) //the upper triangle
{
    interpolatedValue = (1 - fractionY) * data[integerX, integerY] +
                        fractionX * data[integerX + 1, integerY + 1] +
                        (fractionY - fractionX) * data[integerX, integerY + 1];
}
else //the lower triangle
{
    interpolatedValue = (1 - fractionX) * data[integerX, integerY] +
                        fractionY * data[integerX + 1, integerY + 1] +
                        (fractionX - fractionY) * data[integerX + 1, integerY];
}
```

Interpolating between 0, 4, 1 and 3 yields the following result:

[image: Barycentric interpolation]

Comment: Nice answer, may ask what is the tool you used to visualize?

Answer (score 1):

You have two known points:

```
A = (1,2) = 4
B = (2,4) = 5
```

And you want to calculate the value

```
C = (1.5, 2.5) = ???
```

Here's an idea that follows from your linear example. Calculate the linear for each axis. So start with X:

```
Ax = (1) = 4
Bx = (2) = 5
so you calculate Cx as:
Cx = (1.5) = 4.5
```

Then calculate the linear for the y-axis:

```
Ay = (2) = 4
By = (4) = 5
and calculate Cy as:
Cy = (2.5) = 4.25
```

Then average Cx and Cy to get C(x,y)

```
C(1.5, 2.5) = (Cx + Cy) * 0.5 = 4.375
```

Comment: Two points define a line, so the problem is undefind here. What you are doing is blind averaging.

Comment: @ja72 No, it's not blind averaging. This is basically a bilinear interpolation. The more general form is stated in my answer.