# Linear interpolation: calculate correction based on 2D table

Tags: c, math, 2d, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I try to do a thing that should be nothing more than a two-dimensional, linear interpolation but currently I fail finding the correct approach. To describe the problem a bit simplified: there is a drawing area with a size of 3000x3000 pixels where I have to draw e.g. a horizontal line. To do that I'm drawing dots or short lines from every pixel position to the next pixel position which then forms a line.

Now a correction has to be applied to the whole thing where correction information can be found in a (for this example simplified) 4 by 4 array, where every element contains a pair of coordinates describing the values after correction. So a neutral array (with no correction) would look like this:

```
0,0      1000,0      2000,0      3000,0
0,1000   1000,1000   2000,1000   3000,1000
0,2000   1000,2000   2000,2000   3000,2000
0,3000   1000,3000   2000,3000   3000,3000
```

A real correction table would contain other coordinates describing the correction to be done:

[image]

So as input data I have the coordinates of points on the line without correction, the fields values without correction and the correction data. But how can I calculate the lines points now applying the correction values to it so that a distorted line is drawn like shown in right side if the image? My current approach with two separate linear interpolations for X and Y does not work, there the Y-position jumps on a cells border but does not change smoothly within a cell.

So...any ideas how this could be done?

Comment: You need to clip the line segment to each of the patches it intersects, and distort the clipped pieces separately.

Comment: Incidentally, for this sort of thing you'll need bilinear interpolation for the endpoints, not just linear interpolation.

Comment: OK, I'm already interpolating this clipped and for each cell separately...any hints for the bilinear interpolation of this? When I search for it I only find descriptions and explanations for image scaling :-/

Comment: In the non-corrected image, are the lines to draw axis-parallel, i.e. either vertically or horizontally?

Comment: Codor: No, they can be drawn in any direction and angle.

Comment: So you basically have code to draw straight line segments already? Is the correction in vertical direction only?

Comment: Codor: yes, only line(segments) are drawn. The correction itself can be in both, X and Y direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to agree on an interpolation method first. I would suggest either bilinear or barycentric interpolation. In [one of my previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151994/2d-array-interpolation/22153181#22153181) I visualized the difference between both methods.

I'll concentrate on the bilinear interpolation. We want to transform any point within a cell to its corrected point. Therefore, all points could be transformed separately.

We need the interpolation parameters `u` and `v` for the point `(x, y)`. Because we have an axis-aligned grid, this is pretty simple:

```
u = (x - leftCellEdge) / (rightCellEdge - leftCellEdge)
v = (y - bottomCellEdge) / (topCellEdge - bottomCellEdge)
```

We could reconstruct the point by bilinear interpolation:

```
p2       p4
   x----x
   |  o |
   x----x
p1       p3

o = (1 - u) * ((1 - v) * p1 + v * p2) + u * ((1 - v) * p3 + v * p4)
```

Now, the same formula can be used for the corrected points. If you use the original points `p1` through `p4`, you'll get the uncorrected line point. If you use the corrected cell points for `p1` through `p4`, you'll get the corrected line point.

Comment: OK...so p1..p4 can be used once for X and once for Y so that I get X and Y results for o?

Comment: Exactly. It's more convenient to handle them as vectors instead of bare components.