# Interpolation: calculate correction based on 3D table

Tags: math, 3d, interpolation, linear-interpolation, bicubic

This is just for my personal interest and a follow-up to question from [Linear interpolation: calculate correction based on 2D table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23077084/linear-interpolation-calculate-correction-based-on-2d-table)

How would calculation look like when line and correction table use three dimensions - what kind of interpolation and formula would have to be used?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be the same formula as in the original thread, just three dimensions would be used; the approach would be called tri-linear interpolation, as linear interpolation would be used along all three axes. More information can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilinear_interpolation), where also an illustration visualizes the approach. The underlying formula is basically the same as for two dimensions, except that one additional step of interpolation is used.