# How to efficiently find co-planar point in array of 3D points (Terrain)

Tags: arrays, geometry, linear-algebra, terrain, heightmap

I am representing a **terrain** using a two dimensional array height map (500x500) where points are 1 unit apart (1 unit = 1 meter in this case).

I am also representing a **player** using a 3D-point which is represented as (x-float,y-float,z-float). Since the players positioning allows for fine-tuned positioning while the height map is lower resolution, i need a method to find the approximation of the height (z-axis) of the character based on the x/y coordinates that he falls within the terrain height-map (co-planar point).

Therefore my question comes in two parts:

1. How to find co-planar point where the x/y portion of the co-planar point is already solved for?
2. Is there a recommended library that can handle this in C#?

Comment: Perhaps search for "interpolation"? If I understand you correctly, you seek an interpolation of the player's coordinates within the terrain data.

Comment: See, e.g., [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151994/2d-array-interpolation/22153181#22153181).